por que no me funciona el enrutamiento que estoy realizando ya que sigo paso a paso un curso
aqui dejo los codigos implicados y los unicos modificados o creados ya averigue por todo lado pero no encuentro la solucion:
app.module.ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { routing } from "./app.routing";

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    routing
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

y app.routing.ts
import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { ModuleWithProviders } from "@angular/core";
import { HomeComponent } from "./components/home/home.component";

const appRoutes : Routes = [
    { path: '',component:HomeComponent }
];

export const appRoutingProviders : any[] = [];
export const routing : ModuleWithProviders<any> = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);

y en app.component.html solo elimine todo el contenido y pegue <router-outlet></router-outlet> para que se viera el contenido de home
les agradezco cualquier ayuda que tengan.

Estas tratando de importar routing como un modulo y eso no hace nada, veo que tienes  ./app.routing y ./app-routing.module, la configuracion que tienes en ./app.routing es la que deberia estar en ./app-routing.module.

dañe muchas gracias
